# Git commit shows changed files like metadata although they are in gitignore file

Tags: eclipse, git, github

The information on the commits on GitHub says there are thousands of additions and deletions in files such as metadata even though the metadata is in the gitignore file.
This is how looks like my gitignore file:

.metadata

bin/

tmp/

*.tmp

*.bak

*.swp

*~.nib

local.properties

.settings/

.loadpath

.recommenders

.springBeans

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

You probably added certain files to .gitignore after they had already been tracked by git. If this is the case, you need to tell git to untrack the file:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```